# Recognize specific numbers from table image with Pytesseract OCR

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-recognition, python-tesseract

I want to read a column of number from an attached image (png file).

[image: click to see image]

My code is

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os

img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_path, image_name), 0)
config= "-c 
        tessedit_char_whitelist=01234567890.:ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config)
```

This code gives me the output string: 'n113\nun\n1.08'. As  we can see, there are two problems:

1. It fails to recognize a decimal point in 1.13 (see attached picture).
2. It totally cannot read 1.11 (see attached picture). It just returns 'nun'.

What is a solution to these problems?

Bests

Answer (score 1):

You need to preprocess the image. A simple approach is to resize the image, convert to grayscale, and obtain a binary image using Otsu's threshold. From here we can apply a slight gaussian blur then invert the image so the desired text to extract is in white with the background in black. Here's the processed image ready for OCR

[image]

Result from OCR

```
1.13
1.11
1.08
```

Code

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import imutils

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

# Resize, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
image = imutils.resize(image, width=400)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Blur and perform text extraction
thresh = 255 - cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5,5), 0)
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
print(data)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Just wondering (1) why you have to resize am image such that width=400? (2) why you set ksize parameter in GaussianBlur to be (5, 5)?

Comment: The image is enlarged to help the OCR process, the amount that you enlarge the image is arbitrary. The Gaussian blur kernel is set to `(5,5)` to help smooth the image and remove tiny dots before thresholding. Its just a typical kernel size. Other sizes that can work are `(3,3)` or `(7,7)` depending on the image and the amount of noise present